# can you paint over peeling drywall?

Tags: drywall, painting

My drywall is peeling a little:

[image]

The paper sheet has ripped.

Can you paint right over the board is the fact that the paper has ripped... means I need to replace the sheet itself?

To reiterate, I want to remove the peeling paper ofcourse befor paiting. But my concern is, does removing the peeling paper precludes me from paiting over the gymsym board itself that is under the paper?

Answer (score 2):

That damage is from excessive exposure to water. It should be cut out and replaced. If you choose not to, you could get rid of the mildew by spraying with a bleach solution, after it dries, carefully cut away all the loose paper and give a skim coat of drywall compound for the paint to go over, since the gypsum core that is exposed is not really meant for finishing with paint.

I have in one occasion, in a restaurant, used white unsanded grout as a skim coat in a small area as yours where it was getting continually wet so it would hopefully hold up better. Paint is still the main barrier here regardless and a sound surface to keep the paint layer intact

Comment: Grout makes a really tough surface, I have used sanded where I was trying to make it look like a stucco wall.+